# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I got this error after changing Google play ads to latest version.

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.2.0

**app.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.3.0'
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "xyz",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "xyz"]

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'//11.8.0

    implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'//3.6.2 // 3.8.3
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.2.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**project.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'//2.2.3

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'//3.1.1

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

As a result, how can I solve my problem?
I can not solve my problem how can I solve it? Thanks for any response.

I am game developer :)

Comment: The latest version of that `play-services-analytics` library is 17.0.0. What made you think there was a newer version?

Comment: In fact, I haven't updated gradle files for a long time. Today I tried to update them. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android Latest version is 17.2.0 according to firebase doc

Comment: OMG! I used wrong implementation. Let me check. I must have used  com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
not 
play-services-analytics

Answer (score 0):

When setting multiple Google API `implementation` directives, they sometimes depend on specific version of other libraries from the Google SDK.

Sounds like the issue is that there is another `implementation` directive that requires a version compatible with the `play-services-analytics` version you are trying to upgrade to.

To solve the issue, I would :

1. Create a separate standalone module that doesn't require any gradle dependencies .. for example, if there are no Java or XML files.
2. Copy over the gradle file you are trying to make work
3. Comment out all `implementation` directives (probably google-related ones is enough, but can't be sure)
4. Uncomment just the 1 line you are trying to update:

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.2.0'
   ```
5. Then one-at-a-time , uncomment the other `implementation` directives - each time running the gradle sync to make sure the project builds correctly.
6. When you uncomment the line that causes the build to break again, then see if there is an update for that line that caused the build to fail again; I'm guessing there is an update, and so set it to use the updated version as well.